# no llama metodo en jsf

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

estoy desarrollando una aplicación con jsf y tengo este face, lleno una tabla a partir de la base de datos y con un commandlink al final de cada registro que me muestra en un dialog otra tabla con el nombre de los estudiantes inscritos, en esta también tengo un commandlink que llama un método del bean para eliminar el estudiante del curso,pero cuando doy click no me ejecuta el método, ni siquiera lo llama

gracias por su ayuda

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>

        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:breadCrumb>
            <p:menuitem value="Categories" url="/cursos" />
            <p:menuitem value="Registro Alumnos" url="faces/vistaAlumnos.xhtml" />
            <p:menuitem value="Consultar cursos" url="#" />

        </p:breadCrumb>


        <br/>
        <br/>
        <h:form>
            <p:dataTable value="#{cvc.cursitos}" var="cur">
                <f:facet name="header" >
                    Cursos Existentes
                </f:facet>
                <p:column headerText="Id Curso">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{cur.idCurso}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Nombre">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{cur.nombre}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Cupo">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{cur.cupo}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Inscritos">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{cvc.alumnosDelCurso.get(index)}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <p:commandLink value="ver alumnos inscritos" onclick="PF('dlg1').show();"  actionListener="#{cvc.seleccionarCurso(cur)}" update="@form:tabla" >
                        <f:attribute name="click_cur" value="#{cur}"/>
                    </p:commandLink>
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

            <p:dialog   header="Alumnos Inscritos"  widgetVar="dlg1" modal="true" height="300">
                <p:dataTable id="tabla" value="#{cvc.alumnosDelCurso}" var="alumno" >
                    <f:facet name="header"  >
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{cvc.curso_name}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:column headerText="Id alumno">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{alumno.idAlumno}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="documento">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{alumno.documento}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="nombre">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{alumno.nombre}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:commandLink value="eliminar alumno"   actionListener="#{cvc.eliminarAlumno(evt)}"  >
                            <f:attribute name="click_alm" value="#{alumno}"/>
                        </p:commandLink>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:dialog>  
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: ya te aseguraste de que este metodo exista? #{cvc.eliminarAlumno(evt)} asegurate de que este bien escrito, si dices que ni siquiera lo llama, algo tienes mal escrito

Comment: si, estoy trabajando con NetBeans como ide y cuando agrego el nombre del bean + tab me aparecen los métodos, intente con otro método del bean y tampoco lo llama

Comment: no se si tenga que ver algo con el update del form que se ejecuta líneas mas arriba

Comment: talvez, intenta borrando el update

Comment: cuando quito el udpate el dialog no permanece en el face, lo que conlleva a que no pueda ver el usuario la tabla de estudiantes inscritos :(

Comment: añade un onclick al de eliminar alumno, es que tengo tiempo sin usar JSF xd, si añades el onclick y no funciona verifica que el value este correcto

Comment: ya lo solucione por si a alguien le sirve, todo va en el scoped del vean pues lo tenia en request, debía cambiarlo a session para que me siguiera ejecutando los métodos, de igual forma muchas gracias por tu ayuda, no sabia que también eres Colombiano

Comment: bien, respondete tu mismo la pregunta para que los demas sepan, y de nada por la ayuda :D por cierto como sabes que soy colombiano ? xd

Comment: por tu perfil xd

Answer (score 1):

ya lo solucione por si a alguien le sirve, todo va en el scoped del vean pues lo tenia en request, debía cambiarlo a session para que me siguiera ejecutando los métodos